# two functions in <a tag?

Tags: javascript, html, image, href

I have this:

```
<div id="click"><a href="link.html"><img src="img/image.png" alt="something"></a>

<a 
   onmouseover="ReverseContentDisplay('cont'); return true;"
   href="javascript:ReverseContentDisplay('cont')">
info
</a>
</div>
<div id="cont"></div>
```

Right now, when I mouseover the bit of text that says 'info', `<div id="cont"></div>` appears. However, I now need to change the markup so that the anchor tag has a link (instead of a javascript function) as well as showing the `cont` div when the mouseover occurs.

Comment: I'm finding it quite difficult to follow your question. Could you consider rephrasing it?

Comment: I'm not sure the edit captures the intent of the original, which I took to mean content was shown on mouseover (not that it replaced anything) and that the href needed to be able to be a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is an example of what you may want to do](http://jsfiddle.net/xwUCF/3/).  It provides unobtrusive Javascript by removing your JS from your HTML.  The HTML is:

```
<div id="click"><a href="link.html"><img src="img/image.png" alt="something"></a>
    <!-- the href attribute below should have whatever link you want -->
    <a id="showCont" href="http://www.google.com">info</a>
</div>
<div id="cont">Cont</div>
```

The javascript would be in a separate file that is referenced from a `<script>` tag and is:

```
window.onload = init; // call init on load

function init() {
    document.getElementById("showCont").onmouseover = function() { ReverseContentDisplay("cont") }; // set up the onmouseover handler
}

function ReverseContentDisplay(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    if(elem.style.display === "block") {
        elem.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        elem.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

The CSS would also be in a separate file and is the following to hide the cont div:

```
#cont {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what the question is, but if you want to keep the hover and still have a working link, just put the URL in the `href` attribute.

Other tips:
1. What you are doing is not semantic. Look to separate markup from behavior or style. You should add an event listener for click on the link in JavaScript.
2. Keep progressive enhancement in mind, not everyone has JavaScript turned on.
3. Why are you returning true in `onmouseover`? If it has a purpose (though I don't see it) ou should just return true in the function.